# Openpyxl - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm currently trying to read the excel file, check if the quote `category` (third column on the Excel sheet) is "attitude", and if so, then `print` out the first two columns (which are the quote itself and the author).

I'm really stumped because even though I can see that `category` is indeed showing a proper value, the `AttributeError` is telling me otherwise. In addition, I checked the `type` of `category` and it says `str`.

I don't know that much about OOP, so I'm not sure if it's because there's an interference with something in the class itself.

---

Code:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

quotesTable = load_workbook(filename="Motivational Quotes Database.xlsx")

sheet = quotesTable.active
#print(sheet.title)

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5,min_col=1, max_col=3):
    category = row[2].value
    #print(category) - shows a value
    if category.lower() == 'attitude':
        print(row)
```

The website where I downloaded the excel sheet from: https://sharpquotes.com/download-45500-famous-motivational-quotes-database-in-excel-and-pdf/

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: In particular, don't simply claim that the results are valid: give us the stand-alone code that processes and reports that data.  "Shows a value" is not proof that the value is of a type that has a `lower` attribute.  Most of all, the error message clearly claims that `category` is `None`, despite what your narration tells us.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the data has empty cells in the column of interest? You might also want to check for any non-printing characters.

Comment: @Prune That is all of my code. I cannot paste an Excel file into Stack Overflow so I have provided the website where I downloaded it instead. My best guess is that it's misinterpreting `lower` as an attribute since I want it to use the `lower` method that is in the standard Python library.

Comment: @norie As far as I can tell, the C column does not have any empty cells. I'm not sure what non-printing characters are (unless if you mean \n or \t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested you need to check for empty cells and you also need to take into account any non-printing characters, e.g. line feeds.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

quotesTable = load_workbook(filename="Motivational Quotes Database.xlsx")

sheet = quotesTable.active
#print(sheet.title)

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5,min_col=1, max_col=3):
    category = row[2].value
    if  not category is None:
      if category.lower().startswith('attitude'):
        print(row)
```

Comment: How come I can't use the equality operator when determining if `category.lower()` is equal to `'attitude'`?

Comment: There are no values in the 3rd column that match 'attitude' exactly. You can check that using this formula `=COUNTIF(C[-3]:C[-1], "attitude")`.

Comment: So does that imply that there are non-printing characters? If so, how could I detect them?